# Validation rules in laravel 4.2 involving database records

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a created an update function my controller i have this 5 column namely, ID, username, description, and usertype. Since i wanted that all usernames in my records are unique,i added the `unique:dbo_systemusers,SystemUserName`in my rules. My problem is when im updating a certain record say for example username:benny, description:developer, usertype:admin then i wanted to update the description to programmer there would be an error saying that the username already exist. is there a rule where it would only check the username's uniqueness on the other records in the table and not the one im currently at? 
here is my current code for the rules

```
$rules = array(
        'username'     => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|unique:dbo_systemusers,ID,'.$id,
        'description'  => 'required|min:1|max:100|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/',
        'usertype'     => 'required|numeric',
        'capt'         => 'required|numeric'
    );
```

Comment: Can i see your controller where you want to update a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a specific user you must force a unique rule to ignore a given ID.

Try this:

```
$rules = array(
    'username'     => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|unique:dbo_systemusers,ID,'.$id, //you want user $id here to ignore the unique rule
    'description'  => 'required|min:1|max:100|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/',
    'usertype'     => 'required|numeric',
    'capt'         => 'required|numeric'
);
```

Comment: i added it but i had error saying `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dbo_systemusers` where `SystemUserName` = 23434234 and `id` <> 6)` any ideas?

Comment: What is the name of your id in your database?

Comment: hmm it had `Undefined variable: SystemUserID`

Comment: Can i see your controller?

Comment: its long here is the 1st part

Comment: Where is your controller?

Comment: here is my controller i wasn't able to paste it here because it exceeds the character limit link is http://codepad.org/gvx5rSJ6

Comment: When you `print_r($id)` what is the output?

Comment: where should i put the print_r($id)?

Comment: After your `public function something($id)` and after print_r() type exit;

Comment: the url in my browser is `http://localhost:8080/laravel3/public/viewsu/1` then the value i got from the print_r($id) is 1

Comment: i changed my rule for username and set it to `'username'     => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|unique:dbo_systemusers,SystemUserName,SystemUserID,'.$id,` then there was an output saying `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '6' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dbo_systemusers` where `SystemUserName` = 23434234 and `6` <> SystemUserID)` is there a way to interchange `6 <> SystemUserID`

Comment: Yes. Instead of passing ID passed the Username.

Comment: Passed your username first then try my updated answer.

Comment: hmm i reverted it back to `|unique:dbo_systemusers,SystemUserName,'.$id,` then error said `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dbo_systemusers` where `SystemUserName` = 23434234 and `id` <> 6)` is there a way to make the 'id' to 'systemUserID' ?

Comment: Passed username instead the id. id = systemUserID

Comment: i added this `$uname = Input::get('username');` tjen in my $rules, i made it  `'username'     => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|unique:dbo_systemusers,SystemUserName,'. $uname,` but i get the error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dbo_systemusers` where `SystemUserName` = 11388242 and `id` <> 11388242)`

Comment: What is the output of `Input::get('username');`?

Comment: it is 11388242 it came from my view

Comment: So it's not username. It's an ID.

Comment: `"required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|unique:dbo_systemusers,ID,$id"` Try this